# fastest way to stack ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

### Gist

Basically I want to perform an increase in dimension of two axes on a n-dimensonal tensor.
For some reason this operation seems very slow on bigger tensors.
If someone can give me a reason or better method I'd be very happy.

### Goal

Going from `(4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 16, 8, 4, 4, 1)` to `(4, 32, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 1)` takes roughly `170 second`. I'd like to improve on that. Below is an example, finding the correct indices is not necessary here.

### Example Code

Increase dimension `(0,2)` of `tensor`

```py
tensor = np.arange(16).reshape(2,2,4,1)
I = np.identity(4)
```

I tried 3 different methods:

`np.kron`

```py
indices = [1,3,0,2]
result = np.kron(
            I, tensor.transpose(indices)
        ).transpose(np.argsort(indices))
print(result.shape) # should be (8,2,16,1)
```

---

`manual stacking`

```py
col = []
for i in range(4):
    row  = [np.zeros_like(tensor)]*4
    row[i]=tensor
    col.append(a)
result = np.array(col).transpose(0,2,3,1,4,5).reshape(8,2,16,1)
print(result.shape) # should be (8,2,16,1)
```

---

`np.einsum`

```py
result =np.einsum("ij, abcd -> iabjcd", I, tensor).reshape(8,2,16,1)
print(result.shape) # should be (8,2,16,1)
```

---

### Results

On my machine they performed the following (on the big example with complex entries):

1. `np.einsum` ~ `170s`
2. `manual stacking` ~ `185s`
3. `np.kron` ~ `580s`

Comment: 1) Numpy is nor optimized to deal with array in 13 dimensions (which is clearly not reasonable). 2) your array appear to be huge like 8 GiB since you use complex numbers. 2) all your operations seems to involve a transposition which is known to be very expensive on modern hardware. Additionally, do not expect anyone to optimize a 13D transposition (since >4D transposition are already insane to optimize)...

Comment: so basically it comes down to memory laytout correct? i have a similar sized example  which workd just fine

Comment: Have you tried allocating the result with `zeros` and assigning the original into it?

Answer (score 1):

As Jérôme pointed out:

> all your operations seems to involve a transposition which is known to be very expensive on modern hardware.

I reworked my algorithm to not rely on the dimensional increase by doing certain preprocessing steps. This indeed speeds up the overall process substantially.